# Prevent Windows Ubuntu dual boot problems

Tags: dual-boot

I am using Windows and Ubuntu in dual boot for several years.

After big Windows updates I often got many problems with my dual boot: Windows destroyed my GRUB boot menu, some things in the current linux kernel or something like this. I hate spending hours for searching and finding solutions online.

I want to setup a new system and I want to ask if there are some ways to prevent several dual boot problems (after windows updates / upgrades). I am thinking about forbid Windows to change the bootloader or something like this.

Currently I am using a PC with two SSDs and one HDD. Windows is running on the first SSD, Ubuntu on the second SSD. The HDD is full of data and used by both systems (NTFS).

I want a dual boot solution because I don't want to buy another PC and I need the full power of the hardware (that's why I am not using virtual machines).

Comment: It would be useful to find a resolution for the ongoing issue of Windows messing up Linux, but if boot is frozen, would Windows be able to use the alternate boot options, e.g. Safe mode, Restore, etc?